# Autoclosing tags feature is not Responding

Tags: visual-studio-code, emmet

When I tried to activate the auto closing tags feature in Visual Studio Code's settings, I keep getting this error:

[image: Settings]

Answer (score 0):

You are incorrectly using that setting.  In JSON, array properties need to look something like (for string elements):

`"emmet.excludeLanguages": ["markdown", "blah", "blah1"]`

Try:

```json
{
     "emmet.excludeLanguages": ["yourLanguageOne", "yourLanguageTwo"],
     "emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
     "files.associations": {
        "*.extensionOne": "html",
        "*.extensionTwo": "css"
    }
}
```

Check out Visual Studio Codes [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) about settings for more information.